# How to set a header on node js, and retrieve it in all requests? It is losing after set it

Tags: node.js, http-headers, adonis.js

I'm trying to set a header that will contain the credentials for authorization.

I'm using adonis, but the method to set the header is even not working, I used basic-auth api, but neither worked:

```
request.header('Authorization', 'Basic ${base64credentials}')
```

I'm trying as well with the native nodejs method (I write "response" twice, because I'm using adonis, if I write it only once, it throws an error!):

```
response.response.setHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ${base64credentials}')
```

This last method is working, I can retrieve the header with

```
Response.Response.getHeader('Authorization')
```

**but** I can't retrieve the header from another request!

I made a route that logs the header with

```
 console.log(Response.Response.getHeader('Authorization'))
```

and it logs undefined...

That means the header is getting lost after set the header and end the response.

Here's my code... I'm even doing `response.response.writeHead()`... according to the documentation, it send a response header to the request.

```
const result = yield request.auth.attempt(request.input('email'), 
request.input('password'))

const base64String = new Buffer(request.input('email') + ':' + 
request.input('password')).toString('base64')

response.response.setHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ${base64String}')

response.response.writeHead(200, {'Authorization': 'Basic ${base64String}'})

console.log(response.response.getHeader('Authorization'));

return response.end("ok");
```

How can I set the header without it getting lost?

Comment: wait, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Romain Lanz I'm trying to set the authorization headers for retrieve the credentials with basic-auth api, cause I need to keep logged in an user between multiple apps... But the project's leader, wants to do it with headers. **Thanks for answer my question**